# wait element to be invisible selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to wait for an element to be invisible that exist on the previous step, the previous step is a window that appears and then I want to wait until it's closed to continue with the script, the element from previous step is:

```
//textarea[@id="position_description"]
```

but not sure why it waits more than the specified time on the first explicit wait time:

```
class InputAutocompleteElement(InputElement):
    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//textarea[@id="position_description"]')))            
        driver = obj.driver
        element = self.find_element(driver, self.locator)
        element.clear()
        element.send_keys(value)
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "idOfAutocompleteDropdown"))
        element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Takes more than the 2 seconds to continue with the rest of the lines, I'm not sure if it's related to an implicit wait that I have when I setup the login to access the application, the time for that implicit time is 10 seconds.

Comment: Please share the URL

Comment: To figure out if the mixture of waits is causing the issue as per JeffC's answer, you can set the implicit wait to 0 before the explicit wait that is taking a longer time. Check if the time reduces. Set it back to 10 after this line.

Comment: Thanks guys , the problem is the implicit time , I changed everything to explicit times and works faster than before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Selenium docs](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) state not to mix implicit and explicit waits. That's likely the issue you are seeing.

> WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.

Comment: This is not the answer dear

Comment: @iamsankalp89 Proof? OP states that it waits longer than the specified explicit wait time. Also states that he has an implicit wait of 10 seconds. That's mixing implicit and explicit which results in "unpredictable wait times" according to the official docs linked. What am I missing? What is the answer?

Comment: I don't have issue with Official Doc, but it does not solve the issue that is the Problem. Yes I will try to find

Comment: @iamsankalp89 So what is the problem since you seem to know what it is?

Comment: Thanks JeffC, I have mixed before the explicit and implicit times but this is the first time I face these kind of unexpected wait times.